# how do sites run in IE without asking for "allow scripts/activeX"?

Tags: security, internet-explorer

I have tried googling this and have not come up with any good leads...

I have a webpage I'm testing (it's an html document on my local machine).

When loaded, *IE asks if I want to allow scripts and activeX* (I don't get why they are considered equally dangerous)

Popular sites like cnn.com and stackoverflow.com don't ask me if I want to run scripts, they just do.  How and why does this occur?  Do I have to do something special to keep this from happening?  (There is a prompt, but I don't want this to appear for my normal users)

Answer (score 19):

Somehow IE trusts local documents less than the ones on the Internet.  Which is counter intuitive.  But I'm sure there is a reason... what has no reason or explanation, however, is that if you put the following

```
<!-- saved from url=(0017)http://localhost/ -->
```

at the top of your document, IE will trust it more.

(also how come there is no WTF tag on StackOverflow?  Desperately needed)

Comment: fascinating _and_ infuriating.

Comment: @sova as I type this I still hope that somebody would come here and explain to my *why* does it work like that... or tell me that it doesn't.

Comment: @MK. Here is a detailed explanation: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/23/understanding-local-machine-zone-lockdown-restricted-this-webpage-from-running-scripts-or-activex-controls.aspx
Basically, script in a local document has access to the entire contents of your computer. If an attacker was able to trick you into saving some HTML (e.g. an e-mail message) to a local file and you opened the file, the attacker would effectively gain full access to your computer.

Answer (score 4):

It's because those site aren't running locally, they are running on some other server somewhere else.

If you check out Tools->Internet Options for IE and look at Security, Privacy and especially "Advanced".  You'll see a whole host of options.

Comment: so once I put it up I won't see this?

Comment: @sova - nope.  throw it up on a web server, and see for yourself.

Comment: amazing (and infuriating). gracias

Comment: I don't understand that logic.  The script from the internets are also running as me.  Why does IE trust them more than local scripts?

Comment: @MK - I realized that and took it out.  But a script running on your local machine is a lot more dangerous than one running on a remote location, at least I think it would be, wouldnt it?

Comment: @Jack In my opinion anything running inside IE is way too dangerous.  But assuming IE doesn't allow cross-domain JavaScript, local script should be as dangerous or as safe as a remote one.

Comment: Local script has access to things in the local zone that script running in the internet zone does not have access to.  So, yeah, it asks you if you're sure.  If you're doing local web development you should just run a local webserver.

Answer (score 2):

You can always enable **ActiveX** for offline & online by default. Go to:

**Tools > Internet Options > Advanced > Security** :

```
(✓) Allow active content from CDs to run on My Computer
(✓) Allow active content to run in files on My Computer
```

Answer (score 0):

Import following registries(saving following content as a .reg file) you can get the IE ActiveX always enabled without asking for your decision

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main]
"NoUpdateCheck"=dword:00000001
"NoJITSetup"=dword:00000001
"Disable Script Debugger"="yes"
"Show_ChannelBand"="No"
"Anchor Underline"="yes"
"Cache_Update_Frequency"="Once_Per_Session"
"Display Inline Images"="yes"
"Do404Search"=hex:01,00,00,00
"Local Page"="C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\blank.htm"
"Save_Session_History_On_Exit"="no"
"Show_FullURL"="no"
"Show_StatusBar"="yes"
"Show_ToolBar"="yes"
"Show_URLinStatusBar"="yes"
"Show_URLToolBar"="yes"
"Start Page"="http://www.microsoft.com/isapi/redir.dll?prd=ie&pver=6&ar=msnhome"
"Use_DlgBox_Colors"="yes"
"Search Page"="http://www.microsoft.com/isapi/redir.dll?prd=ie&ar=iesearch"
"Check_Associations"="yes"
"FullScreen"="no"
"Window_Placement"=hex:2c,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,\
  ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,e9,00,00,00,b4,00,00,00,75,04,00,00,54,05,00,\
  00
"Expand Alt Text"="no"
"Move System Caret"="no"
"NscSingleExpand"=dword:00000001
"DisableScriptDebuggerIE"="yes"
"Error Dlg Displayed On Every Error"="no"
"NoWebJITSetup"=dword:00000000
"Page_Transitions"=dword:00000001
"FavIntelliMenus"="no"
"Enable Browser Extensions"="yes"
"UseThemes"=dword:00000001
"Force Offscreen Composition"=dword:00000000
"NotifyDownloadComplete"="yes"
"AllowWindowReuse"=dword:00000001
"Friendly http errors"="yes"
"ShowGoButton"="yes"
"SmoothScroll"=dword:00000001
"Enable AutoImageResize"="yes"
"Enable_MyPics_Hoverbar"="yes"
"Play_Animations"="yes"
"Play_Background_Sounds"="yes"
"Display Inline Videos"="yes"
"Show image placeholders"=dword:00000000
"Print_Background"="no"
"AutoSearch"=dword:00000005

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN]
"iexplore.exe"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN\Settings]
"LOCALMACHINE_CD_UNLOCK"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: Thanks?  I don't think my regular users will be willing to run regedit... but this is interesting.  Can you explain your answer?  I'm curous as to which line actually changes it.. the very last one?

Comment: there are several lines change the settings. I captured these changes via regmon. It should work for your test on your local machine if you import it to registry before your testing. However, if you'd like to bypass the internet security setting on the users' machine, that should be considered as an attack.