# Cannot get the text plugin to work with requirejs in IE

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

**I just can't make the text plugin to work with requirejs on Internet Explorer.**

I get the following error:

```
SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

text.js, line 267 character 13
```

And, after a few seconds, i get the following error:

```
SCRIPT5022: Load timeout for modules: underscore,backbone,text!templates/userListTemplate.html_unnormalized2,text!templates/editUserTemplate.html_unnormalized3,text!templates/userListTemplate.html
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout 
require.js, line 8 character 105
```

I load my files locally, the script works in Firefox and chrome.

Here is my config:

```
// file: main.js

    require.config({

        paths: {
            "jquery" : "libs/jquery",
            "underscore" : "libs/underscore",
            "backbone" : "libs/backbone",
            "text" : "libs/text"
        },

        shim: {
            underscore: {
                exports: '_'
            },

            backbone: {
                deps: ["underscore", "jquery"],
                exports: "Backbone"
            },

            text : {
                exports : 'text'
            }
        }

    });

    require(['app'], function (App) {

        App.initialize();
    });
```

Here is the content of app.js:

```
 // file: js/app.js

define([
'jquery', 
'underscore', 
'backbone',
'router',
'models/user',
'collections/users'
], function ($, _, Backbone, Router, User, Users) {

var initialize = function () {

    // Models to populate the global collection with default values.

    var user1 = new User({
        firstName : 'Sassy',
        lastName : 'The fancy Pussycat'
    });

    var user2 = new User({
        firstName : 'Lola',
        lastName : 'The lovable Saint Bernard'
    });

    var user3 = new User({
        firstName : 'Dany',
        lastName : 'The guy'
    });

    var user4 = new User({
        firstName : 'Aly',
        lastName : 'The cute wife'
    });

    var user5 = new User({
        firstName : 'Last',
        lastName : 'Hoping to be the first'
    });

    // Global collection.

    window.users = new Users([user1, user2, user3, user4, user5]);

    Router.initialize();

}

return {
    initialize : initialize
}
});
```

Next, I load the router.js:

```
// file: router.js

    define([
        'jquery', 
        'underscore', 
        'backbone',
        'views/userList',
        'views/editUser'
    ], function ($, _, Backbone, UserList, EditUser) {

        var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

            routes: {
                '' : 'home',
                'new' : 'editUser'
            }
        });

        var initialize = function () {

            var router = new Router();

            router.on('route:home', function () {

                var userList = new UserList();

                userList.render();
            });

            router.on('route:editUser', function () {

                var editUser = new EditUser();

                editUser.render();

            });

            Backbone.history.start();
        }

        return { 

            initialize : initialize 
        }
    });
```

And finally, here is one of my views:

```
// file: views/userList.js

    define([
        'jquery', 
        'underscore', 
        'backbone',
        'text!templates/userListTemplate.html'
    ], function ($, _, Backbone, userListTemplate) {

        var UserList = Backbone.View.extend({

            el : '.page',

            preLoader : '.preLoader',

            render : function (currentPage) {

                var that = this, 

                    models = users.models,

                    perPage = 2,

                    totalPages = Math.ceil(models.length / perPage);

                if (currentPage == null || currentPage.length === 0) {

                    currentPage = 0;
                }

                var start = currentPage * perPage,

                    end = start + perPage;

                var subset = _.filter(models, function (num, index) {

                    return (index >= start) && (index < end);
                });

                var template = _.template(userListTemplate, {

                    users : subset, 

                    totalPages : totalPages, 

                    currentPage : currentPage
                });

                setTimeout(function () {

                    that.$el.append(template);

                    $(that.preLoader).hide();

                    that.$el.show('slow');

                }, 500);
            }, 

            events : {
                'click .pagination a' : 'click'
            },

            click : function (e) {

                var currentPage = $(e.target).html() - 1;

                this.render(currentPage);
            }
        });

        return UserList;
    });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer tends to get extremely sketched out when you try [to run local scripts on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663509/how-do-sites-run-in-ie-without-asking-for-allow-scripts-activex). That being said, it doesn't look like anything is wrong on your end and when/if you move everything to a server, the problem should resolve itself. Until then, try adding this to the top of your source html:

```
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
```

and also take a look around the web for instructions on how to get IE to accept your local scripts like [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146926/why-does-ie-restrict-the-javascript-files-of-local-html-pages).

Comment: I moved it to a server and had errors, but I was rushing off to work today and I need to double check. What alternatives are there to text.js? Any ideas?

Comment: I added that line of code, I don;t get the "display blocked content warning" anymore, but the errors persist. Maybe it's from the shim, or maybe there is an incompatibility between the libraries used.

Comment: I used my local WAMP install and it works ;) WOW, lucky! :) ty

Comment: If you're using Apache to host the files, they're no longer viewed as local. That's probably what solved the problem.